# MarshalAs attribute case study

Tags: c#, dll, marshalling, native-methods

When should we use this attribute and why do we need it? For example, if the native function in c takes as a parameter a pointer to unsigned char, and I know that it's needed to fulfill the array of unsigned chars, why can't I use array of bytes in C# to use this function? Is it necessary to do marshalling?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The runtime will be able to automatically determine how to marshal data between native and managed code in most cases, so you generally don't need to specify the attribute. `MarshalAs` is only necessary when there is an ambiguity in the definition (and you want to tell the runtime precisely how to marshal the data) or if you require non-default behaviour.

In my experience, `MarshalAs` is only really required when working with strings, since there are so many different representations in native code; unicode/ansi, c-strings or not, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Additional use of MarshalAs attribute is marshalling fixed-size arrays (including fixed-size strings) with ByValArray and SizeConst parameters. For example, many structures from Windows API contain fixed-size strings.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Microsoft documentation for [Type marshaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/type-marshaling)

> **Marshaling** is the process of transforming types when they need to cross between managed and native code. Marshaling is needed because
> the types in the managed and unmanaged code are different. In managed
> code, for instance, you have a String, while in the unmanaged world
> strings can be Unicode ("wide"), non-Unicode, null-terminated, ASCII,
> etc. By default, the P/Invoke subsystem tries to do the right thing
> based on the default behavior, described on this article. However, for
> those situations where you need extra control, you can employ the
> [MarshalAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute?view=net-6.0) attribute to specify what is the expected type on the
> unmanaged side.
>
> Generally, the runtime tries to do the "right thing" when marshaling
> to require the least amount of work from you.

Which types need special handling is explained on the following [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/75dwhxf7(v=vs.71)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) from the doc to **Blittable and Non-Blittable Types**:

> Most data types have a common representation in both managed and
> unmanaged memory and do not require special handling by the interop
> marshaler. These types are called blittable types because they do not
> require conversion when passed between managed and unmanaged code.

**Non-blittable** types would be the answer to your question. You would have to marshal for the following ones:

Array, Boolean, char, class, object, string, value type (structure), delegates, unmanaged arrays that are either COM-style safe arrays or C-style arrays with fixed or variable length.

Unmanaged structures can also contain embedded arrays or Booleans (non-blittable types). There you have to be careful according the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/blittable-and-non-blittable-types):

> Structures that are returned from platform invoke calls must be
> blittable types. Platform invoke does not support non-blittable
> structures as return types.